# CKEditor running in Flex 3?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, ckeditor

I'm interested in integrating CKEditor into my Flex 3 application so that users can generate full HTML documents.  After some quick googling, I am interested in using CKEditor, but I can't find any home-run success stories on using it with Flex 3.  For example, I found:

http://blog.aboutme.be/2009/10/25/ckeditor-running-in-flex-and-air/

and a couple of similar blogs.  Based on posted comments, however, it looks like there either may be integration issues, cross-browser issues, or similar gotchas.

I'd like some advice on scoping this effort and potential pitfalls, and any pointers to useful snippets, tutorials or blogs on similar efforts.  I am also open to better HTML editors for flex -- I just haven't found any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get mine working (with Bob Tate's help setting everything up) without having to use Drumbeat Insight's control.  if you need some help or pointers, email me directly with CKEditor in the subject line.  jeremysl@hotmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You can't really integrate a non-Flex component into a Flex application.

Your best bet is to look into using the [iFrame trick](http://raghuonflex.wordpress.com/2006/12/07/flex-i-frame/) to make it appear as if CFEditor is part of your Flex application.  Google around for iFrame trick to find more info on it.

There is an HTML Component from [Drumbeat Insight](http://drumbeatinsight.com/htmlcomponent) that helps solve a lot of the issues w/ this trick.